# Changing Page Layout without Changing Record Type Possible? Case or Workflow

Tags: record-type, page-layout

I understand that you have to change record types in order the page layout will change.  What if your Record Type is important and you dont want it to change.  Instead, you just want certain fields or buttons to show after a picklist is selected after update.

I have a few users who are pretty good going around the system and breaking them.  So I was planning of removing buttons and some picklist until the other team selects the picklist then it will be visible for them to approve.  make sense?

Scenario:
Team A = Production
Team B = Clients

Layout 1 is blank for TEAM B until TEAM A selects the picklist "APPROVE" then after saving it will change to LAYOUT 2 so TEAM B will see a new field for them to select to move forward.  Possible?

If I create a record type then TEAM B will just select that record type when creating new and will give them the option to move forward without approval from TEAM A.  So it doesnt make real sense.

Any ideas?  I just want it to go to another page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck on the situation you describe. However, there are things you can do. If you give both teams a different profile, then you can either give each profile its own page layout or, even better, prevent one of the teams from using a specific record type when creating a record.

If the profile-based solutions don't work for you then you can always resort to Visualforce. If you want that, shout and I can help with some sample code.

Comment: I was thingking of the same concept and it's the same idea I have.  Thanks for the idea